# Pl help me for the comment input format for site comments

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I want an input format for comments for site visitors who will not use html. However all line breaks should be retained and html special characters need to be escaped including the hiding of email ids.

Can somebody tell me if these settings are ok and will not affect my site in any way ?:

http://drupalworld2011.blogspot.com/2011/07/creating-drupal-comment-input-format.html

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's totally fine. Don't forget to apply this format as default for comments.